# jQuery Mobile Nested List - Normal Emphasis text is being hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, listview, mobile, jquery-mobile

With a nested list in jQuery Mobile the normal text disappears when you have a sub list. Here is the example Code:

```
<div data-role="page">
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
            <h1>Header Text 1</h1>
        Normal Text 1
        <p>Sub Text 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Header Text 2</h1>
        Normal Text 2
        <p>Sub Text 2</p>
        <ul>           
            <li><p>Sub item 1</p></li>
            <li><p>Sub item 2</p></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Header Text 3</h1>
        Normal Text 3
        <p>Sub Text 3</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The text `Normal Text 2` is not visible in the nested list.

Here is a screen shot:
[image: Notice the missing text in item #2]

I've also put together a jsfiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/stani/2WwGC/
UPDATE: Fiddle wasn't correct - should be correct now.

Is there any way to make the 'Normal Text 2' show up? Or perhaps it's a bug with the jQuery Mobile framework?

Comment: I tried it with a span tag and label tag and both these tags increase the emphasis for "Normal Text 2" but work correctly for "Normal Text 1" and "Normal Text 3" in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI seems to extract certain HTML tags from your original list and rewrite them in a fancier way, based on their semantic meaning (`<h1>` become titles, etc...). It seems to me that "orphaned text" is not handled properly.

In any case, I see no reason not to wrap your "Normal Text" in a `<p/>` or `<div/>`.

Comment: Generally speaking I think you're right. However, from the documentation it seems to imply that using no wrappers is a valid way to have "normal" text in a list view. Look under heading "Text formatting & counts" here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html 

From the documentation: "To add text hierarchy, use headings to increase font emphasis and use paragraphs to reduce emphasis"

Comment: He did have a good point though. Why not wrap your text in a p tag?

Comment: In a nutshell, using a paragraph or div (or span, or label) tag does not work. The text is styled differently based on the tags (or no tag). According to the documentation the styles applied (which are shown in the example above) are as follows:  header tags = increased font emphasis and paragraph tags = reduced emphasis, and no tag = normal emphasis on text. What I am trying to accomplish is Normal emphasis, not lighter or stronger emphasis, so using a paragraph or header (or div, etc) tag would not work.